# Don't click until button is released

Tags: java, button, lwjgl, slick

Hello i'm making a simple game right now, and I have it when your on the play screen you can press esc to open up the menu. There is a main menu button which takes you from the play screen to the main menu screen, and the problem is it takes them to the main menu screen, but then clicks the button which is in the same spot on the main screen as the ingame menu, so it clicks the button on the main menu before you are able to release the button. Here are some of my classes

this is my menu class (Main screen) http://pastebin.com/kc5Dx2bp

this is my play class (The play screen) http://pastebin.com/Gr3y9Amj

Is there a way to make it so you can't click another button until the mouse button is released?

Comment: please post an SSCEE (http://sscce.org) to help your helpers, because it's much simpler to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can use the `ButtonModel` to track finer changes to the button state then `ActionListener` gives you.

This example monitors the `armed` and `pressed` states of the model and takes action based on a certain condition.

This is a small trick, as the state you are looking for will occur not only when the button is released, but also when the button is first pressed.  What we do is wait until the previous state had the button pressed and the buttons `pressed` state is `false`, then we know we have a button release

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestButton05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestButton05();
    }

    public TestButton05() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JButton btn = new JButton("Clicked");
                btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    private boolean wasPressed = false;
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
                        if (model.isArmed() && !model.isPressed() && wasPressed) {
                            System.out.println("Released");
                        } else {
                            wasPressed = model.isPressed();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(btn);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using gaming libraries called slick 2d and lwjgl. I'm using if statements to check if the mouse position is inside the area of the printed button image (using pixel coordinates) and if the mouse button is down. How would I check if the mouse button is up, so that no other if statements are triggered untill the mouse button is released from the first if statement.

Comment: You could set a flag in the equivalent mouse handler that trips on mouse down/up events

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not exactly an expert at java what do you mean by flag?

Comment: A `boolean` variable whose state you can change based on some condition (for example, when the mouse pressed, you can set it to true and check it else where in your code when you need to)

Comment: Ohhh. Here is an example of a button on my code :   if((mousePosX>=300 && mousePosX <= 510)&&(mousePosY>=285&&mousePosY<=320 && goMenu == true)){
   if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
    sbg.enterState(0);
   }
And when I do Mouse.isButtonDown(0) There is no way to check whether the mousebutton is up.

Comment: I would assume (not been farmilar with Slick2D) the `Mouse.isButtonDown(n)` would return `true` if is down and `false` if it's not.  If `false` then the button isn't pressed

Comment: Ohhh yeah thats right thanks I could easily do 
if(!Mouse.isbuttonDown(0)){
buttonIsUp = true;
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a boolean in your class called canClick.
2. Create a MouseListener.
3. Add the MouseListener to each button (button.addMouseListener(...);)
4. In the MouseListener, implement all needed methods.
5. Set the boolean to true or false as needed in each method.
6. When a button is clicked (ActionListener), check the boolean.
7. If false, cancel it (or just disable all buttons until true)

Something like that.

Comment: IMHO - `MouseListener`s on buttons is rarely a good idea.  I'll admit there are probably a very small number of edge cases where it might be required, but I'd exhaust all my other options first - but that's just me